# Print out Array in Javascript by given name

Tags: javascript, json

In my console log I got:

[image]

I want to achieve a list in my console log like:

`michael,klaus`

I don't know how to print the JSON object out without the other variables.

**server.js:**

```
var arrayUsers=[]

   socket.on('user-connected', (userName_)=>{
        console.log(userName_ + " joined " +socket.id)


        arrayUsers.push({
            socket_id: socket.id,
            userName_socket: userName_
        })

        console.log(arrayUsers)

        socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected',userName_)
        socket.emit('online-users',arrayUsers)

        socket.broadcast.emit('online-users',arrayUsers)

    })
```

**index.html:**

```
socket.on('online-users',(arrayUsers)=>{
 
    arrayUsers.forEach(elem=>{
        console.log(elem.userName_socket)
    })
})
```

Comment: [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: So did you tried anything yet ? any code... For a hint, go to google and try to search what you are trying to achieve. Another hint, try to learn what does `Array.map()` do

Comment: ‘console.log(array.map(el=>el.userName_socket))‘

Comment: Pictures of code don’t constitute code, please add your code to the question, *as text*, and then format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `.forEach` loop over the array and push each `elem.userName.socket` to another array. Then print the new array.

```
const arrToPrint= [];
    arr.forEach(elem=>{ arrToPrint.push(elem.userName.socket);
 })
console.log(arrToPrint);
```

If you don't care to print each username line by line, replace the `.push` by a console log.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr.forEach(elem=>{
  console.log(elem.userName.socket)
})
```

You can traverse through the array to get the required elements in a array.

Answer (score 0):

You can map through the array using .forEach

```
arr.forEach( el => console.log(el.userName_socket))
```

Comment: my console output looks like : ``` arrayUsers=>arrayUsers.userName_socket```

Comment: @du7ri Are you sure you are not using console.log outside the forEach statement? Given arrayUsers is the array of objects from which you're getting the data, it should work perfectly fine